# Manipulate 3d touch items from extension

Tags: swift, widget, ios-app-extension, 3dtouch

I would like to modify shortcut items of my app's 3d touch menu while the app isn't running but it's extensions are.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40170790/7216259) states, there should be a way to manipulate 3d touch items from within the widget. How can this be done, since the shortcutItems is an attribute of UIApplication, which has no connection to the widget.

Comment: Please see the answer to a similar question, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52524821/2941876